# iOS ad-hoc build not installing on device

Tags: ios, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created an ad-hoc build for my app and I have added the UDID's of a couple of devices in the iOS dev centre. It seems that the app installs on one of them but doesn't on the other. Is this a common problem? Am I supposed to do anything else other than just adding the UDID?

Comment: Check you didn´t forget any character in this UDID and check if the iOS version is compatible with your app

Comment: The ID is correct and the device is an iPhone 5. My app supports iOS 6 and upwards.

Comment: Did you checked this device in your dev center portal as Ad-hoc? maybe you forgot to check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that, you forgot to add the Provisioning Profile which has added(UDID) into it.

> Include the Profile to the App and then choose the same while creating
>   archive of it

[image]

For more info [Check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: Yes. This was the problem. I was using the provisioning profile without including these devices.